# Discrete Math - Set intersection

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

[image: Solve for D.]

When I tried solving for d I got the following:
B1 = { -1 < x < 1 }
B2 = { -2 < x < 2 }
B3 = { -3 < x < 3 }
B4 = { -4 < x < 4 }
B5 = { -5 < x < 5 }

I am unsure as to why the answer is  { -1 < x < 1 }

Comment: It is the set of $x$'s which satisfy **all** of the inequalities simultaneously.  $\cap$ represents intersection, i.e. $a\in (\bigcap B_i)$ iff $a\in B_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: And for the record, it should be $\{\color{red}{x\in \Bbb Q}~:~ -1<x<1\}$

Comment: The sets $B_i$, $i=1,2,3,4$ you have computed are not correct. Check them!

Comment: @HoneyBee that should be right??

Comment: As you have written it, it appears as though every real number between $-1$ and $1$, as opposed to only the rational numbers.  Also the notation is off

Comment: @JMoravitz i understand the notation being incorrect, if i fix the notation will everything be correct?

Comment: still do not understand as to why the answer is { -1 < x < 1 }

Comment: @Keving if you fix these notations, as pointed out by JMoravitz then the answer is the set $B_1$

Comment: @HoneyBee But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bigcap_{i=1}^{5}B_i$ is the same as $B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3 \cap B_4 \cap B_5$.  So in order for an element to be in the intersection of these 5 sets it must be in all of them.  It should also be clear that $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset B_3 \subset B_4 \subset B_5$, so the only elements that are in all 5 sets are exactly all of the elements of $B_1$.